# Group data by frequency and estimate % per groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this DataFrame `df`:

```
ID  EVAL
11  1
11  0
22  0
11  1
33  0
44  0
22  1
11  1
```

I need to estimate the % of rows with `EVAL` equal to 1 and 0 for two groups: Group 1 contains those `IDs` that are repeated more than or equal to 3 times in `df`. Group 2 contains `IDs` that are repeated less than 3 times in `df`.

The result should be this one:

```
GROUP    EVAL_0    EVAL_1       
1        25        75
2        75        25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the percentage of IDs that are repeated three or more times with [`value_counts()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and then using a boolean index with [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mean.html).

```
>>> (df.ID.value_counts() >= 3).mean()
0.25
```

This is the gist of the work, but depending on what you wanted to do with it, if you wanted output like yours you could just create a DataFrame

```
>>> g1_perc = (df.ID.value_counts() >= 3).mean()
>>> pd.DataFrame(dict(group=[1, 2], perc_group=[g1_perc*100, (1-g1_perc)*100]))
   group  perc_group
0      1        25.0
1      2        75.0
```

The second column with the opposite percentage looks a bit needless to me.

Comment: Could you please explain why do you use `mean()`? Doesn't it calculate mean values?

Comment: @Dinosaurius `(df.ID.value_counts() >= 3)` yields a boolean series with `True` for whatever ID's have a count greater than 3, and `False for those that do not. Then `mean()` is summing the integer values of the booleans (0 and 1) which here represents the percentage which match our criteria, namely that the count is greater than 3.

Comment: I tested your approach in my real data frame and results are weird. I validated the results as follows: `freq = df.ID.value_counts().reset_index()
mylist = freq[freq['ID']>=3]
test = df[df["ID"].isin(mylist.ix[:,0])]
test.groupby("EVAL").size().reset_index()`. This gives me absolute values for group 1, and if I convert them to %, I get different results from what I get using your method. Could you please help?

Comment: @Dinosaurius Your final line there yields a DataFrame with eval group `0` having size 1 and eval group`1` having size 3. That is, 1 ID with at least three occurrences and 3 IDs with less than 3 occurrences. Then 1/4 = 0.25 which is the same result that my solution provides.

Comment: Yes, but if I run the code on my extended data set, the results are different. Anyway, thank you. Perhaps I had to post more representative data.

Comment: @Dinosaurius Probably having to do with your index manipulations? You're welcome - I can assure you that this way works :)